# DB2 SQL Error-=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=SYSCAT.SCHEMATA in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: jdbc, db2, oracle-sqldeveloper

As the title describes, when trying to connect to a database I have been granted permissions to via SQL Developer, I am presented with the message
An error was encountered performing the requested operation:

```
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=SYSCAT.SCHEMATA, DRIVER=4.26.14
Vendor code -204
```

, and the schema viewer is empty. I have both the db2jcc4.jar and db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar files added to my driver path, and both files were provided by the database admins. I don't know what this error means beyond the object not being defined in DB2, please help me figure out what's causing this and some potential solutions.

Running `select * from sysibm.sysversions` results in the message `DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=SYSIBM.SYSVERSIONS, DRIVER=4.26.14`

Running `SELECT GETVARIABLE('SYSIBM.VERSION') FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1` results in `DSN12015`

Comment: Are you connecting to a Db2-for-Z/OS database,  or a  Db2-fori- (as/400) database?    The message is saying that `syscat.schemata` does not exist (it expsts when the Db2-server runs on linux/unix/windows).

Comment: I am not sure, how do I check? I am able to access the data through queries, it's only the schema view that doesn't work.

Comment: I have updated the question with the relevant details

Comment: I have updated the question with the output for that query, does that mean I am using DB2-for-Z/OS when I shouldn't be? How can I switch to the correct setup?

Comment: You are connecting to a Db2-for-Z/OS database.  Seems that the Oracle-SQL-Developer does not correctly support that flavour of Db2-server in its current configuration.  Which version of Oracle-SQL-Developer are you using?

Comment: Java(TM) Platform 1.8.0_221,
Oracle IDE 20.2.0.175.1842

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Oracle SQL-Developer tool is designed to work best with the Oracle RDBMS.

Support for IBM's Db2 products seems to have some gaps, so it may not work fully with either Db2-for-i (as/400),  or Db2-for-Z/OS (to which you are currently connecting).  But sometimes those functional gaps do not matter, and you can continue to use the tool despite some missing functionality. It depends on your skills and your expectations.

If you need to use a GUI tool, and you specifically need that GUI tool to understand the Db2-for-Z/OS features, then you should instead use the "IBM Data Studio" version 4.1.3 and then apply its APAR5 (or higher). This is , like Oracle-SQL-Developer, a tool written in java, and a free download, although IBM's tool is based on the Eclipse toolset so it has a large footprint and requires to be updated with fixes (APAR5 or higher) to resolve various bugs.

Get IBM Data Studio 4.1.3 via https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/download-and-install-ibm-data-studio-version-41x

Get fixes (i.e APAR5 or higher) via https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/fix-packs-ibm-data-studio

Comment: DB2 connectivity/support limited to LUW for DB2 => Oracle Database migrations